# When NOT to use useEvent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React 18 introduced the new `useEvent` hook.

This new hook seems so great that i'm wondering when **NOT** to use it ?

Appart from the case where i need to explicitly control the referential stability of a callback (and in that case i would use `useCallback`), i do not see any situation where `useCallback` should be preferred over `useEvent`.

Do you know any "cons" about using `useEvent` over `useCallback` ?

Can i safely convert (nearly) all my `useCallback` to `useEvent` ?

Thanks !

Comment: At this time according to the beta docs, useEvent solves a different problem, which cant be directly achieved with useCallback,
I had a similar question which explans the use case for useEvent https://stackoverflow.com/q/74551749/2122822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: `useEvent` is not part of React at the moment.  They are simply planing to add the hook in the future. (As of React 18.2.0.)*

---

This is answered in [the RFC for `useEvent`](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/d85e257502a43c08d17e8ab58efa0880f7f007a5/text/0000-useevent.md#when-useevent-should-not-be-used):

> Some functions need to be memorized but are used during rendering. `useCallback` works for these cases. [...] Since `useEvent` functions throw if called during render, this isn't much of a pitfall.

There are several more examples in the RFC, I don't want to copy all of them here.