# Need to refer to latest state inside event handler registered from useEffect on load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

`useEvent` solves the [problem](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md#useeffect-shouldnt-re-fire-when-event-handlers-change) of reading latest props/state in a callback inside `useEffect`, but can't be used in production yet [Nov 22].

It's use case is also [documented in beta docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/separating-events-from-effects#declaring-an-event-function) as well

The problem

```
const SomeComponent = ({ prop1, ...}) => {

const [state, setState] = useState('initial')


useEffect(() => {

      // inside the connect callback I want to refer to latest state and props and I dont want to reconnect on state change
      // here event handler, depends on prop1 and state
      const connection = createConnection(...)
      connection.on('connect', () => {
        // will refer to prop, state
        // without these varaibles in depedency array
        // this effect will not see the latest values
      })

      return () => {
         connection.disconnect()
      }


}, [])
```

`useEffect` depends on depends on `prop1` and `state`, causing unnecessary reconnections.

Some patch work like solution using `useRef`

```
const SomeComponent = ({ prop1, ...}) => {

    const [state, setState] = useState()

    const someFunction = () => {
      // use latest props1
      // use latest state
    }

    const someFunctionRef = useRef()
    someFunctionRef.current = someFunction;

    useEffect(() => {

      const someFunctionRefWrapper = () => {
           someFunctionRef.current()
      }
  
      // need to read the latest props/state variables
      // but not rerender when those values change
      const connection = createConnection(...)
      connection.on('connect', someFunctionRefWrapper)

      return () => {
         connection.disconnect()
      }

}, [])
```

Right now useEvent can't be used in production, I am thinking of creating a custom hook to solve the problem

```
const usePoorMansUseEvent(callback) {

  const itemRef = useRef();

  itemRef.current = callback;

  const stableReference = useCallback((..args) => {
    itemRef.current(...args)
  }, []);

  return stableReference;

}
```

- Is there any better approach, am I reinventing the wheel

Comment: You never told us what your specific problem is. Chances are this hook is unnecessary. Why are you putting this function in a `ref`? What is this `register` function?

Comment: Sorry I was not  clear about the use case, I edit the question to include an example of the problem in general, since the callback can be regsitering to any event inside a `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just make two `useEffect`s, one for connecting / disconnecting and one for refreshing the callback.

If you just want a connection on mount:

```
    const [connection] = useState(createConnection(...));

    useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
         connection.disconnect()
      }
    }, [connection])

    useEffect(() => {
      connection.on('connect', someCallback)
      return () => {
         // Disconnect previous callback on change, idk the actual syntax
         connection.off('connect', someCallback) 
      }
    }, [connection, someCallback]
```

That follows the whole immutability principle.