# After sending each message there becomes 2 more messages using socket io

Tags: reactjs, sockets

I have a React website.
I receive messages like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('message', message => {
        console.log(message)
    })
}, [socket])
```

I send messages like this:

```
socket.emit('chatMessage', { message, id })
```

Server side:

```
socket.on('chatMessage', ({ message }) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', message)
})
```

First time there is 2 message (1 for the user who sent it), the next time there is 4, 6, 8 and so on.

Comment: cleanup is needed, I has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74580584/2122822) this related question in some details,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up the connections from the previous renders

```
useEffect(() => {
      
    let isValidScope = true;

    socket.on('message', message => {
        console.log(message)
        // if message received when component unmounts
        // stop executing the code
        if (!isValidScope) { return; };

        // if you need to access latest state, props or variables
        // without including them in the depedency array
        // i.e you want to refer the variables without reseting the connection
        // use useRef or some custom solution (link below)

    })

     return () => {
       // cleanup code, disconnect
       // socket.disconnect()
       isValidScope = false;
     }
     
}, [socket])
```

more about [useEffect life cycle](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects), to get an idea why

- A new effect is created after every render
- How the cleanup for previous effect occurs before executing of current useEffect

You can read about why isValid is set [synchronizing with effects](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data)

Why it was running 3 times in [dev mode](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development)

If you are intererested in taking a deep dive, consider reading a blog post by [Dan on useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-everything), its old but helps to build a good mental model about useEffects and functional components.

[useEvent](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/separating-events-from-effects#declaring-an-event-function) can solve the problem but it is in [RFC](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md)

you can check my question about a implementation to build a [custom useEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74551749/2122822) till it becomes stable

Hope it helps, cheers

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you assume your component will never be recreated. But React does not provide such guarantees. And if you will add logging at the place when you open a socket, you will notice that for the first render it will be called 2 times. And because you do not have cleanup code the socket remains open even after the component is destroyed. Thus duplicated messages.

Furthermore it would seem that your component is recreated on every message, which multiplies the existing effect of duplication.

The solution in your case would be to close the connection in cleanup part of the effect.